# UML drawing tool with round-trip support

Tags: uml, code-generation, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to choose a tool for creating UML diagrams of all flavours (for at least class, activity, sequence, use cases, and state machine) with java round trip support. Usability is a major criteria for me, and also if it is free or if it has any version for non commertial use.

I have tried severals but if they have drawing support for so different diagrams, they do not have round trip support, and vice versa.

Options such as UML Generators is not an option (I have found it difficult to use and I am not competely sure that it works), Green UML is a bit obsolete.

I am thinking about trying PlantUML or Visual Paradigm for non commertial use.

Any idea? Does anybody have used them or others?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Forget about round-tripping. No tool works well in that respect. Best you can get it "sort of works". Enterprise Architect would be one. Else I just know RR which was at a ridiculous price (guess RSA is similar).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. Finally, I decided to use Modelio which allows me to draw several type of diagrams and do round trip of class diagrams (also integrated with Eclipse). Enough for what I needed.